# AWS-EC2 instance -ICMP not working -Direct Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, icmp

I have got a EC2 instance spun up in AWS and we are connecting to AWS via Direct Connect. So when i go to a switch on my side, i could see BGP Peering is established and could ping the cross-link IP.

I have  created a another network(10.0.0.0/24) on the switch and advertise them to AWS. So when i tried to ping from that new network as source to EC2 instance i couldn't but when i plug in a laptop and did RDP i can see it on wireshark capture but not ICMP.

Route Table, NACL & SG looks good.

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 0):

If you could connect through RDP but couldn't got ping your problem is in either firewall rules for ICMP or settings for ICMP, or both.

Comment: Thanks Stan for the response. We don't have any firewall between our switch and AWS (it's a direct cable going into AWS).   Secondly, I tried different options with ICMP on NACL & SG but no luck.